# is it possible to modify the scipy differential_evolution algorithm?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, differential-evolution

I need to try several boundary constraint-handling methods in Differential Evolution, so I would like to know how to  modify the original differential_evolution  scipy algorith, is that possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.optimize.differential_evolution` already has simple box-bounds, as well as [`NonlinearConstraint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint.html) and [`LinearConstraint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint.html). The latter two use the [Lampinen approach](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html#r108fc14fa019-5).

If you wish to experiment with other constraint mechanisms you will probably have to modify the `scipy` source [code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.9.2/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py) directly.